# Displaying the JSON string

Tags: jquery, .net, json

This is what I have done

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST", url: "Data.aspx/CheckInsertRecord",
            data: "{EventType:'" + eventtype + "',BeginDate:'" + begindate + "'," +
                   "EndDate:'" + enddate+"' }",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
            var data = $.parseJSON(msg.d);

           alert("A record of this event already exists in the database.
                  \n" +  msg.d+".");

            }});
```

SO what happens in code behind is:

```
public static string CheckInsertRecord(String EventType, String BeginDate, String EndDate)
{
    NCDCPoint ncdc = new NCDCPoint();
    CEOSurveyDataContext CDC = new CEOSurveyDataContext();
    int et = Convert.ToInt32(EventType);
    CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
    DateTime b = Convert.ToDateTime(BeginDate);
    DateTime e = Convert.ToDateTime(EndDate);
    DetailsView a = new DetailsView();



  var query = (from n in CDC.NCDCPoints
                where n.EVENT_TYPE_ID == et && n.BeginDate == b && n.EndDate == e
                select new { 
                   n.EVENT_TYPE_ID,
              BeginDate =  n.BeginDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd",provider),
               EndDate = n.EndDate.ToString(),
                n.BeginLAT,
              BeginLONG =  n.BeginLONG,
                n.EndLAT,
                n.EndLONG});

   if (query.Any())
   {
       return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(query.ToList());
   }
   else
   {
       return "No duplicate";
   }

      }
```

The code may not be of much use. However, the JOSN string would be displayed pretty ordinarily. I tried to use details view but was not successful. SO, can u guys please tell me the way so that I can print JOSN string a good format. This is how my JSON string is displayed right now:

```
{"EVENT_TYPE_ID":1,"BeginDate":"2011-06-03","EndDate":"2011-06-11",
 "BeginLAT":null,"BeginLONG":null,"EndLAT":null,"EndLONG":null}
```

Answer (score 2):

If this is simply for your debugging needs, then I would suggest using Firebug for Firefox.  It will show you all of the AJAX requests and the server response coming back.  If the response is properly formatted JSON it will give a nice collapsible view of the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirements you want to display the JSON returned.

Could you not make use of the data variable you are setting with $.parseJSON?

That would provide you with an object, containing the JSON values.

e.g.

```
 var data = $.parseJSON(msg.d);
```

would give you something like

```
 data.EVENT_TYPE_ID
 data.BeginDate
 //etc
```

so you could use this to build up a display string in whatever format suited you best.

Comment: I wanted to display it in correct foramt. But the problem has been that when I try to display them seperately I' getting undefined i.e., I tried alert(data.EVENT_TYPE_ID);  and alert(data[EVENT_TYPE_ID])..In two cases I'm getting undefined.

Comment: I see.. looking again, why are you doing $.parseJSON(msg.d) and not $.parseJSON(msg)?

Comment: Thats because, .NET will add the d element at root when "BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped" is declared. You can use WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare to remove it

Comment: The JSON result from the WCF service will be like {
    "d": {
        "EVENT_TYPE_ID": 1,
        "BeginDate": "2011-06-03",
        "EndDate": "2011-06-11",
        "BeginLAT": null,
        "BeginLONG": null,
        "EndLAT": null,
        "EndLONG": null
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

Although I am not clear of the problem but it looks like you are trying to call the C# code from jquery and you are successful to do so.

To get the JSON object in your code, just try:

```
<html>
```

```
    function test (data) 
    { 
        var a = $.parseJSON(data);
        alert(a.EVENT_TYPE_ID);
    }
    function load()
    {
        test('{"EVENT_TYPE_ID":1,"BeginDate":"2011-06-03","EndDate":"2011-06-11","BeginLAT":null,"BeginLONG":null,"EndLAT":null,"EndLONG":null}');
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="load()">
</body>
</html>
```

It works for me.

Comment: I wanted to display in some good format for the users to view say something like details view. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display after processing it . Take a look at http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx

You can de-serialize it as object and print it nicely.